# ExtJS 5. How to remove rounded corners from fieldset border?

Tags: extjs

In `ExtJS 5` a fieldset component has rounded border corners by default (at least they are rendered so in Firefox, Ubuntu). What I want are old-style sharp corners. I looked through sencha documentation, but could not find appropriate configs.

Comment: Look under css variables http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldSet

Comment: I see that $fieldset-border-radius is by default 0, though it is definitely not. And unfortunately I do not know how to use these variables.

Comment: Hi this is a fiddle with a default fieldset and I don't see Round Corners. Are you sure you are not changing your CSS somehow and causing this problems? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/coo

Comment: @Guilherme Lopes Thanks for this fiddle. In this demo I changed style from crisp to classic (Ext JS 5.0.1.1255 Classic) and I see these notorious round corners. In ExtJS 4.2 and all previuos versions there were no round corners by default. PS. I'm not sure whether it is browser dependent, so, just for information, I'm using Firefox.

Comment: By the way, in classic mode panels are also looking terrible by default.

Comment: Oh, I checked this fiddle in prior versions. You can also do it and see, that in ExtJS 4 fieldset and panel borders had sharp corners. Classic is no longer classic any more -))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacobian,

Thanks for specifying that your issue is with the classic theme.
It seems that every container has round-corners by default, so everything that extends from the `Ext.container.Container` will have round corners.

Regarding your fieldsets you could add a class to your main container (eg. myContainer) and use CSS to specify that every fieldset inside your container shouldn't have round corners:

```
.myContainer .x-fieldset {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

If you want to remove round corners from every single fieldset in your project no matter where it is, change the `.x-fieldset-default` class:

```
.x-fieldset-default {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

I've updated my fiddle with this first choice.
http://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/coo